# Operation with classes

Tags: c++, class, operation

I am trying to get a result with the attributes of two different classes.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*Se hizo el uso de archvios tipo "header" para hacer el codigo mas entendible, tambien en este archivo .h
 se omitio el uso de su respectivo .cpp ya que al compilar se generaba el error de "Redefinir cada una de 
 las clases" esto se presentaba ya que el .h que se incluia en el .cpp era el mismo codigo y hacia una 
 compilacion doble, la solucion fue copiar ese codigo y pegarlo en el .h eliminado asi el .cpp y el problema.*/

/*Se generan 5 clases ya que de esta forma la implementacion de las sobrecargas se hace de una forma mas sencilla*/

class clsDensity{
    float density;
public:
    clsDensity(){}
    clsDensity(float densidad){
        density = densidad;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDensity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.density >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDensity &s){
    o << s.density << " Kg/m^3";
    return o;
}


class clsDynamicViscocity{
    double dynamicViscocity;
public:
    clsDynamicViscocity(){}
    clsDynamicViscocity(double viscocidadDinamica){
        dynamicViscocity = viscocidadDinamica;
    }
    friend istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s);
};

istream& operator >>(istream &i, clsDynamicViscocity &e){
    char sign;
    i >> e.dynamicViscocity >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign >> sign;
    return i;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream &o, const clsDynamicViscocity &s){
    o << s.dynamicViscocity << " N/m^2";
    return o;
}

class clsAtmosfericConditions{
    clsAtmosfericConditions(){}

    float kinematicViscocity(class clsDensity, class clsDynamicViscocity){
        float kinematicViscocity;
        kinematicViscocity = clsDensity::clsDensity(float)/clsDynamicViscocity::clsDynamicViscocity(double);
        return kinematicViscocity;
    }
};
```

I want to get the kinematic viscosity ratio of the density and dynamic viscosity, but I have a issue with this line:

```
kinematicViscocity = clsDensity::clsDensity(float)/clsDynamicViscocity::clsDynamicViscocity(double);
```

Xcode displays this message: "Expected '(' for función-style cast or tape construction" in when I define float and double.

I think the problem is when I pass by reference to clsDensity and clsDynamicViscocity, and so with the methods.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish with `float kinematicViscocity(class clsDensity, class clsDynamicViscocity)` ? Did you intend on ignoring whatever variables were passed as parameters to that member function?

Comment: `clsDensity::clsDensity(float)` is a declaration of a constructor, not a function call.   You're trying to use it in a statement like it is a function call, hence the diagnostic.

Comment: Try describing what you are trying to achieve - you have not actually given that information.   Your code is invalid, but there is no point in anyone trying to give pointers to fix it, unless you are clear about what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: @Peter I want to obtain the ratio of `density` and `dynamicViscocity`. These two are attributes of two different classes. In this line `kinematicViscocity = clsDensity::clsDensity(float)/clsDynamicViscocity::clsDynamicViscocity(double);` I am trying to make a function call. @WhozCraig In that line I trying to pass by reference `cld Density` and `clsDynamicViscocity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran it through gcc. For the line you state, it complains:

```
stuff.cpp: In member function ‘float     clsAtmosfericConditions::kinematicViscocity(clsDensity, clsDynamicViscocity)’:
stuff.cpp:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
stuff.cpp:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
stuff.cpp:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘(’ token
stuff.cpp:62: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
```

which makes a lot of sense. These functions (which happen to be constructors) take a `float` and `double`, respectively. So you need to pass them `float` and `double` *objects*. When you write `float`, it's a type, not an object (ditto for `double`), and you can't call a function with it.

---

Changing the offending line to

```
 kinematicViscocity = clsDensity::clsDensity(0)/clsDynamicViscocity::clsDynamicViscocity(0);
```

(which is not what you want necessarily, but I can't guess further), changes the complaint to

```
 stuff.cpp: In member function ‘float clsAtmosfericConditions::kinematicViscocity(clsDensity, clsDynamicViscocity)’:
stuff.cpp:62: error: no match for ‘operator/’ in ‘clsDensity(0.0f) / clsDynamicViscocity(0.0)’
```

which again makes sense - this constructs two objects, the combination of which is not supported by `operator/`. If you would like to overload this operator for the types, see [this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/) or [this one](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/arithmetic.html).

Comment: I understand that I am not passing the object, instead, I am passing the constructors. Also in the last part of the answer you wrote that the `operator/` do not support the combinación of two objects, so how can I do that operation?.

Comment: @OscarEspinosa Added a link to a tutorial how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add public accessors to both the `clsDensity` and `clsDynamicViscocity` so other code can access values of their private members.

```
class clsDensity
{
     float density;
 public:
       // other stuff you have

      float GetDensity() const {return density;};
      void SetDensity(double d) {density = d;};
};
```

and, similarly, for `clsDynamicViscocity`.

Then change the member function `clsAtmosfericConditions::kinematicViscosity()` to something like (if it is within the class definition)

```
float kinematicViscocity(const clsDensity &d, const clsDynamicViscocity &v)
{
    float kinematicViscocity_value;
    kinematicViscocity_value = d.GetDensity()/v.GetViscocity();
    return kinematicViscocity_value;
}
```

All of the differences between the above and your code are relevant.

1. `kinematicViscosity` cannot directly access `private` members of
   other classes (`clsDensity` and `clsDynamicViscosity`).  Those
   classes either need to provide public accessors as I've done here or
   (inadvisable except in specific circumstances - which are not the
   case here) declare `clsDensity` and `clsDynamicViscosity` as
   friends).
2. You cannot use the name of a constructor to access private members
       of a class, like you have tried.
3. Member functions generally have a different name than the class they
       are in.  Non-static members need to be supplied with an instance of
       the class (i.e. the object).
4. `clsDensity::clsDensity(float)` is the declaration of a constructor
       for `clsDensity()`.    It does not provide some magical means -
       implied in your usage of it - to get the value of a density.
5. Having a variable with the same name as a function tends to confuse the compiler.

If the above points don't make sense to you, that means you need to spend more time reading a basic textbook so you do understand rather than just relying on guesswork and hacking code.   The things I'm describing are basic and fundamental to C++, and are described in basic texts on C++, but both your code and this question demonstrate you have failed to understand.